# In which order should I level the parts of my character?

Tags: genshin-impact

Genshin Impact has various things which are related to your character progression, and it can be hard to focus on what to do first.

These areas are...

- Character level
- Weapon level
- Artefacts
- Talents

What is the optimal order for levelling up these aspects of a character? I am Adventure Rank 53, so to make use of new characters they take quite a bit of investment. As such optimising the process to make them useful early is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your AR, you already have access to the biggest drops

My answer for your resin usage would be:

- Weapon mats/Talent mats on the days they're available
- World bosses for leveling and ascending your character
- Artefacts if your character has reached your desired ascension and the weapon/talent mats you need are not available

And remember, not all talents are worth upgrading, and only use your fragile resin when you want to refresh for artefact farming as it is the only big RNG factor in your upgrades